# Python closes immediately after running script

Tags: python

FIXED IT BUT WONT LET ME DELETE

As described by the title, I am trying to run a pretty long script that closes immediately. It closes immediately without showing me the output.

Here is what I've tried:
I've attempted adding `input('Press ENTER to exit')` and it didn't work. I also tried doing that same command but replacing exit with close and putting `exit ()` under it, as well as `exit(0))`.
I've also attempted opening it with `python myfile.py` and nothing. I've tried almost everything I could find.

I'm on Windows, I'm running the script directly from the file, I downloaded it and attempted to run (Sorry if this isn't clear I'm new to Python). The script is long so I don't know if it'd be useful putting it here, also it's kind of private stuff.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your relevant code.

Comment: Not a lot of information to go on here. Is this Windows? Are you running the Python script from command prompt, powershell shell, programmer IDE, something else? Does the script run to completion or does it terminate early, well before the terminating input that you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

```py
quit_control=input("Do you know to quit? press 'Y' and enter for quit.")
while quit_control!="Y":
    quit_control=input("Do you know to quit? press 'Y' and enter for quit.")
```

Comment: So can you tell me what to put? Very new to Python and all coding in general. Assuming it's something like input('Do you want to quite?') if('y') exit()

Comment: Didn't work sadly.

Comment: The program does not close until "Y" is entered for this code.

Comment: I know, after editing it to what you said, it still closed immediately.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I fixed it, the problem was I had python 10 and 3.7.9 installed and for some reason since i had two versions installed it would close. thanks anyway